# Linq to sql not filtering result as expected

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following query:

```
string oversite = "AB";

 var wherequery = from result in t_staging_trts_mpmnmcp
                         where cutstrings.Contains(result.TYDLNO)
                         && result.source_system_instance.Contains(oversite)
                         select result;
```

"oversite" is a string in this instance it is "AB"
"cutstrings is a list of strings

The problem I'm having is that the query return results outside of oversite.  "AA", "AC", "AD"

I have also tried:

```
&& result.source_system_instance == oversite
```

Why does the && seem to act like an || (and seems to act like or?)

Comment: Have you looked at the generated SQL? It really should be okay...

Comment: you should show the type definition of `result`. I doubt you have some mixed-up concept here. How do you extract the `AA, AC, AD` from the result?

Comment: @JonSkeet, no I don't understand why either.  I've exposed the sql and the only thing I can see is that it treats the contains like a "like" but passes a parameter \@p431, which I cannot see.

Comment: @KingKing I tried to make it `IQueryable<t_staging_trts_mpmnmcp>` but the results stay the same.

Comment: You should be able to see the parameter values in the log...